# Etale cohomology approach on $\tau(n)$

Tags: number-theory, etale-cohomology

Ramanujan's $\tau$ conjecture states that $$\tau(n)\sim O(n^{\frac{11}2+\epsilon})$$ which is a consequence of Deligne's proof of Weil conjectures. Answers in [Status of $\tau(n)$ before Deligne](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1205419/status-of-taun-before-deligne/1205516) tell that best exponent before Deligne reached $\frac{29}5$.

What was it that cohomological approach gave that broke the traditional approach barrier to reach $5.5$ in exponent?

Comment: This is way beyond me. But I once tried to get an overview on Deligne's proof, and I found a survey/expository article by Nick Katz. In his Leitfaden the Ramanujan $\tau$ is one of the nodes. IANA an algebraic geometer, but I would guess that $\tau$ makes an appearance in 11th cohomology of some variety - this is probably not accurate. Anyway, Katz' survey may help you more than it ever helped me.

Comment: please post your survey links.

Comment: Katz' survey appeared in print some time in 70s-80s. Deadwood produce was the default media at the time. I don't have a link. I searched for it with methods fitting the early 90s. I trust you have command of more efficient search methods. Don't count on it being available on-line.

Comment: While there are people here who can probably help you, there are possibly more such people on [MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net), since it devoted strictly towards research-level questions.

Comment: Indeed, for the same question on MO with answers see [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/201068/etale-cohomology-approach-on-taun).